# org.json.JSONException: JSONArray[0] not a string

Tags: java, arrays, json

Hi i am trying to parse json  My json looks like:

```
"data":[[0,1,0],[0,2,0],[0,3,0],[0,4,0],[0,5,0]]
```

i am using  following code to perform action

```
int k=0;
for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++)
                {
                    String data = json.getJSONArray("data").getString(k);
                    data = data.substring(1, data.length() - 1);
                    String[] countArr = data.split(",");
}
```

Following Excetion i am geting;

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONArray[0] not a string.
    at org.json.JSONArray.getString(JSONArray.java:333)
    at com.inrev.analytics.manager.impl.IRticsManagerImpl.userActivity(IRFbAnalyticsManagerImpl.java:4276)
    at com.inrev.analytics.action.facebook.IRFsightsAction.pageUserActivity(IRFBInsightsAction.java:4004)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:870)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1293)
    at ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
```

Comment: `json.getJSONArray("data")` return a `JSONArray`, not a `String`

Comment: i think json above is not valid, a `{` at begin and `}` and end is missing

Comment: Not really sure at the moment, but I guess that there is some kind of "getList()" function. Consider carefully reading the error message first before posting it here...It says "not a string", you are calling "getString()". Kinda visible what the problem is here.

Comment: its a `array` inside an `array`. so be careful to fetch the `data`

Comment: you had initialised with numbers then how can you expect string from initialised data??

Comment: initialised part of yours is a number and there is another code that you had dealt wrong as one should add \"\" for data to parse and i did not see in your code please go through basics again.

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite clear. The first element is not a `String` but a `JSONArray`

Do something like this

```
JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");

for (int i=0; i<data.length(); i++) {
    JSONArray element = data.getJSONArray(i);
    //Do something with your element
}
```